# When would not using asyncio make sense?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrent.futures

In what cases would one threads or executors (using threads) over `asyncio`?

As my experience using Python (CPython) has progressed, it has centralized around optimizing scripts at work to do some form of web services call in bulk and process responses. However, after several generations of script builds, I find myself wondering why I would ever not use the latest?

Allow me to provide some context below...

**Problem:** Request N files from Server A onto Client B, process and save to disk.

1. Sequentially

   - Build container of requests, send single request, process response, repeat until done
   - Probably considered the "standard/beginner" approach as it's intuitively reached
2. Multi-Threaded

   - Again build container, but send multiple requests concurrently
   - Use a Semaphore to limit active connections
   - Use a Queue to share between workers and dump responses
   - Let the main thread process the responses
   - Essentially, workers are fire-and-forget and main runs in a loop checking Queue for data
   - Keeps a separation of concerns away from main which solely processes data
3. ThreadPoolExecutor

   - Essentially like Solution 2, except a lot fewer lines of code
   - Reasoning: "I would like to be able to process a response as soon as it's available"
   - Explicit instantiation of Queue and Semaphore not required
   - If not mistaken, use of a Queue and Thread structure is use in `as_completed()`
   - Pretty much outlined [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)
4. asyncio

   - Introduce a serious confusion here, but concept mostly understood
   - Operates on a single thread unlike Solutions 2 and 3
   - Closer (very) to Solution 3 in implementation except for writing to disk
   - Requires use of a Solution 3 component to save to disk via `run_in_executor()`

Thus we have arrived at my current dilemma: why would I ever **not** want to use `asyncio` for I/O bound work?

Asynchronous programming is a concept very much like OOP, and the docs for Solution 3 even say "asynchronous execution can be performed with threads". But if I can achieve asynchronous execution on a single thread (excluding an additional thread for blocking I/O to disk), why would I ever want to use Solutions 1-3?

I know that given the GIL, CPython multi-threading is suboptimal; regardless, I see no reason why anybody would ever use threads or executors anymore. I've done a fair bit of Googling to see if I can uncover a good article saying why one would prefer to use them, but I've only found articles saying why threads (and subsequently executors using threads) are bad: context switching (GIL/OS), race conditions, resource starvation, etc...

Since CPython doesn't use threads to take advantage of multiple core CPUs (thats the `multiprocessing` library I believe), threads are not used for heavy computational tasks; thus limiting them to I/O bound operations for performance gains. That, however, doesn't give me enough reason to understand why threads or executors would be used over `asyncio`.

If you can do it all in a single thread (maybe 2-3) why keep introducing the overhead of creating, managing and destroying threads (both explicitly and through a pool/executor)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the decision between multithreading and asyncio would really be which kind of multitasking you need. If everything is under your control in a program, asyncio/multiprocessing might be the right choice all the time. However, maybe you want to start a task where preemtive multitasking is the right choice. For example, you start a task in a third party library. An obvoius reason to use threads would be that the library does not support asyncio. However, even if its supporting asyncio, maybe you don't want to trust that library to give control to your tasks as often as you want. You then could start a new thread with another asyncio event loop that runs that code.

So I think the real question is: When to use cooperative and when to use preemtive multitasking.